# calculating frequency in arrayList

Tags: java

the below code works good but I want to add a method to calculate frequency of the integers in the arraylist. For example: 90-99 freq: 3.... 80-89 freq 6

What is the best way to go about? Should I make an if statement that counts++ each variable?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class gradeSorter{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
{
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("grades.dat"));
double average;
double deviation;
double sum = 0;
int number = 0;
int newnumber = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> element = new ArrayList<Integer>();



while (scanner.hasNextInt())
{
element.add(scanner.nextInt());


}
for (int item : element){
        sum += item;
        System.out.println(item);
}

average = sum / element.size();

for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++)
{ 
newnumber += Math.pow((element.get(i) - average),2);

}


deviation = Math.sqrt(newnumber / (element.size()));




System.out.println("The average of these grades is : " + fmt.format(average));

System.out.println("The standard deviation of these grades is: " + fmt.format(deviation));  


}
}
}
```

----jGRASP exec: java gradeSorter

```
51
52
55
57
58
61
62
63
66
66
66
70
72
73
74
75
75
77
77
78
79
81
82
84
86
87
88
91
94
97
The average of these grades is : 73.233
The standard deviation of these grades is: 12.288

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405154/how-to-count-repetition-of-words-in-array-list)

Comment: If all numbers are < 100 you could just create an `int[100]` and store the frequency of each number. Or an `int[10]` to store each x0-x9 range.

Comment: @James, don't remove the code. It is important to provide context for the question and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of size `10`, which holds the frequency of numbers in each range:

```
int[] rangeFrequency = new int[10];
```

Now, for all the numbers in range - `[0,9]`, frequency would go in index 0. For range `[10, 19]`, the frequency would go in index 1, and so on...

Now the point is how you get that index for all those range? Here's how:

**Pseudocode:**

```
for each element in list
    bucket = element / 10   // For range [0-9], this will give index = 0
                           // For range [10-19], this will give index = 1
    rangeFrequence[bucket] += 1;
```

---

**Code:**

```
int[] rangeFrequency = new int[10];

for (int elem: element) {
    int bucket = elem / 10;
    rangeFrequency[bucket] += 1;
}

// Print frequency from array:
for (int i = 0; i < rangeFrequency.length; ++i) {
    System.out.print("Frequency in range : [" + i * 10 + ", " + 
                                                 (i * 10 + 9) + ") --> ");
    System.out.println(rangeFrequency[i]);
}
```

Note that you need to take care of *ArrayIndexOutOfBounds*, when your `grade < 0 || grade >= 100`, the above program will crash.

Comment: You may wish to add bounds checking on `bucket` to be safe. You don't want user input to be able to crash your program, and a grade of 110 or -1 would throw an OOB.

Comment: @JasonC. Yes right. I'll edit the answer. Or I'll rather leave that for an exercise for OP.

Comment: I am a big fan of "exercises for the OP".

Comment: @Rohit Jain, I'm trying clean up the table you're printing a little. I want it to just say <=59 = 5. So it has 6 graderanges total, and 6 frequencies.

Comment: @James. Edited the print statement. It will however print `0` for range that is not there. You can fix that however.

Answer (score 4):

Start by using an integer array as big as the maximum value you expect. As this looks like grades maybe we can assume the largest value you'll get is 100?  If so code like this would work.

```
int[] freqMap = new int[100];
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    int indexValue = list.get(i);
    freqMap[indexValue]++;
}
```

Look at this and think. So when a grade of 3 comes in, we get the value at the 3rd index, and increment it. If that happens 10 times the first **4** values in our frequency array would look like:

```
0 0 0 10
```

This is because arrays are 0-indexed. Here the frequency of index 3 is 10.

Edit:

Iterate over the structure to get the frequency of a particular range. This is trivial. I'll demonstrate here:

```
//the frequency aggregate for the range 80-90
int freqFor80To90 = 0;
for(int i=80; i<90; i++){
    freqFor80To90+=freqMap[i];
}
System.out.println("The frequency for 80-90 is "+freqFor80To90);
```

Storing the frequency for all numbers is slightly more expensive in terms of heap, but allows you to query many different ranges faster than calculating the frequency of an entire range using the original data set.

The solution I provide gives you a structure, `freqMap`, to query for frequency ranges. That's what I'm doing in my code sample above; querying the structure for the frequency of a particular range.

Other solutions give you arrays holding frequencies of entire ranges, which is perfectly valid. My solution, however, offers more flexibility because it offers a finer view of the original data set at the expense of a little more memory.

Comment: Yes, let me edit... you could use an integer array but it won't work as well for data with high variance.

Comment: @James You already used `ArrayList`, so it's time to learn [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) ;-)

Comment: @William Morrison, If you don't mind can you post the int array method, just so I can see how it's done.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison If I understand the question correctly, the OP requires the frequency for a range of numbers, say from 80-89 and NOT the frequency of one number. In the HashMap Solution it will give the frequency of a particular number but not the range. Let me know if am missing anything.

Comment: This will not find frequency of range, but for each element.

Comment: Right thanks guys. I've demonstrated how to calculate frequency of a range now. My solution is more flexible than finding the frequency of a particular range I think.

Comment: @William Morrison I'm a little confused on how to  implement your method. I'm trying to create a table of grade ranges and frequencies.

Comment: Right. My method above will give you all frequencies for all grades. You iterate over the structure it builds to get the frequencies of grades over a particular range. Did you see my edit?

Comment: @JNL If your ranges are equal size, you can use grade/rangeSize (e.g. grade/10) as the hash key. If your ranges vary in size, you can create a Range object to represent a range, determine which Range the grade is in, and use that as the hash key. You could also substitute anything else that functions as a map instead of a hash map (e.g. an int array indexed by grade/10, with proper bounds checking, or an ArrayList that you search through brute force). The concept is the same: `rangeCount[rangeKey(grade)] ++` (pseudocode). What `rangeCount` and `rangeKey` are is flexible.

Comment: If you do use a custom key type in a HashMap don't forget to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` for the key type.

Comment: Right, Jason and I suggest the same thing, except I'm using a bucket size of 1, and he of 10. He's calculating a structure which will hold your solution immediately, I'm creating a structure you'd need to query for the solutions. That's what I demonstrate at the end of my answer.

Comment: @JasonC I agree if the keys were stored with some operations, as you said, range/10 so then it would definitely work fine. That was not implemented in the HashMap code earlier, so thought its better to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a array of integers for this:

```
int[] counters = new int[NUMBER_OF_BUCKETS];

while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
  int n = scanner.nextInt();

  // Determine which bucket this int should be in:
  int bucket = determineBucket(n);

  //Count the integer in the appropriate bucket:
  counters[bucket]++;
}
```

The `determineBucket()` method takes a number and decides into which bucket it should be counted (a bucket is just a set of numbers, in your case a bucket would be the range 80-89, for example). The simplest way to code your buckets is the following:

```
private static int determineBucket(int n) {
  if(80 <= n && n < 90) {
    return 0;
  } else if(90 <= n && n < 100) {
    return 1;
  } else if(...) {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you are actually grouping the numbers in ranges of length 10 you can do better than the previous code, but I can't be sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: you can write `determineBucket` with simple statement `return n/10-8`

Comment: Agreed, if indeed he is grouping by ranges of length 10 (see comment at the end of my answer). We can't be sure, though!

Comment: `counters[bucket]++` will not chande value in array.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29)

```
java.util.Collections has the method:
public static int frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o)
```

"Returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to the specified object."

Comment: This would only count the frequency of an individual number, he wants the frequency of a range.